# Node AWS S3 get object metadata?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to store a user's uploaded files in S3 using presigned URLs. This works fine, but I'm using UUIDs as the filename to avoid conflicts. I need to be able to save the file's original filename, so I'm passing it as metadata in the signed upload URL:

```
const url = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', {
  Bucket: UPLOAD_BUCKET,
  Key: key,
  Expires: AWS_UPLOAD_EXPIRATION / 1000,
  ContentType: contentType,
  Metadata: {
    filename: originalFilename
  },
});
```

This also appears to work fine (the metadata is showing in the AWS console). How can I access this metadata? When the client needs to display one of these images, they request a presigned download URL from the server which is generated like this:

```
const url = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('getObject', {
  Bucket: UPLOAD_BUCKET,
  Key: key,
  Expires: AWS_DOWNLOAD_EXPIRATION / 1000,
});
```

This URL doesn't appear to include the metadata, and the return value of `getSignedUrlPromise` is a string, so there doesn't seem to be any room for anything other than the URL itself. I assumed there would be an S3 method for fetching just the metadata, but as far as I can tell it doesn't exist (or has an unintuitive name). This is especially confusing considering the `getObjectTagging` and `getObjectLegalHold` methods exist. How can I access metadata through a presigned URL? If that's not possible, how can I fetch the metadata using the AWS SDK? If that's not possible, I must be misunderstanding the point of metadata.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You cannot fetch metadata using URL, but you can use `s3.headObject` method:

```
const config = new AWS.Config({
      accessKeyId: 'your acessKey',
      secretAccessKey: 'your secret',
      region: 'your region',
    });
const s3 = new AWS.S3(config);

const params = {
  Bucket: 'your bucket',
  Key: 'your assetKey'
}
const metaData = await s3.headObject(params).promise();
```

[Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#headObject-property)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This will work great. Of course the function for getting an object metadata isn't called `getObjectMetadata`..

Comment: What if I want to retrieve both the object and its metadata? With the current approach, you need to make two requests: getSignedUrlPromise and headObject, correct? That seems to be rather ineffective when you want to obtain information about the same object - is there a way of performing that in a single request?

Comment: const {Body, Metadata} = await  s3.getObject({Bucket, Key}).promise() gets you both metadata and object @Bianca

Comment: For AWS SDK for JavaScript v3, see [```headObject``` § S3 | S3 Client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/s3.html#headobject) and the [```HeadObjectCommand```](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/headobjectcommand.html) class.